# Signature of a manifold as an invariant

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Could you help me to see why signature is a HOMOTOPY invariant? Definition is below (from Stasheff)
The \emph{signature (index)} $\sigma(M)$ of a compact and oriented $n$ manifold $M$ is defined as follows. If $n=4k$ for some $k$, we choose a basis $\{a_1,...,a_r\}$ for $H^{2k}(M^{4k}, \mathbb{Q})$ so that the \emph{symmetric} matrix $[<a_i \smile a_j, \mu>]$ is diagonal. Then $\sigma (M^{4k})$ is the number of positive diagonal entries minus the number of negative ones. Otherwise (if $n$ is not a multiple of 4) $\sigma(M)$ is defined to be zero \cite{char}.

Comment: Cohomolgy groups are diffeomorphism invariants, but ?

Comment: Cohomology groups are homotopy invariants.

Comment: Cohomology groups are not diffeomorphism invariants! For example, Milnor's exotic spheres show this. Although I am sure there are other easier examples. For example, take any smooth thickening of a manifold...

Comment: Note that the signature is an *oriented* homotopy invariant, i.e., it is invariant only under orientation preserving homotopies.

Comment: @SeanTilson: Cohomology groups are invariant under homotopy equivalence, and thus under homeomorphism, and thus under diffeomorphism. Milnor's exotic spheres are all homeomorphic--- and thus, in particular, cohomology spheres--- but not diffeomorphic.

Comment: Yes, but they do not distinguish between different diffeomorphism classes. I guess I was less than clear by what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using a more invariant definition of the signature. First, cohomology and Poincaré duality are both homotopy invariant. It follows that the abstract vector space $H^{2k}$ equipped with the intersection pairing is a homotopy invariant. Now I further claim that the signature is an invariant of real vector spaces equipped with a nondegenerate bilinear pairing (this is just [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)). So after tensoring with $\mathbb{R}$ the conclusion follows.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "the intersection pairing"?

Comment: @wqr: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory#Topological_intersection_form .

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "absolute value" of the signature is a homotopy invariant, not the signature itself! Indeed, $\sigma(-M) = -\sigma(M)$ ($-M$ is the manifold with the opposite orientation). And of course $M$ and $-M$ are diffeomorphic: the identity is a (reversing orientation) diffeomorphism from M to -M.

Comment: You are right that the signature is not a homotopy invariant, but a orientation preserving-homotopy invariant. But wording it the way that you did might confuse @wqr. It is better to point out, that one has to restrict only to homotopies which preserve the orientation.