# Why is the signature of a manifold homotopy invariant?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, poincare-duality

I'm going through some applications of Poincaré duality for de Rham cohomology in Greub's Connections, Curvature and Cohomology. I was wondering about the homotopy invariance of the signature of a compact oriented $4k$-dimensional manifold and found [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159036/signature-of-a-manifold-as-an-invariant). In this case the signature $\mathrm{sig}(M)$ of $M$ is defined as $\mathrm{sig}(M):=\mathrm{sig}(P_{M}^{2k})$ where the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form
$$P_{M}^{2k}:H^{2k}(M)\times H^{2k}(M)\to \mathbb{R}$$ is given by
$$([\alpha],[\beta])\mapsto \int_{M}\alpha\wedge\beta$$

I cannot seem to understand why the signature is a homotopy invariant, as stated in the first answer of the aforementioned question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition you've given for the signature is phrased in terms of de Rham cohomology and is indeed not obviously homotopy invariant. However, the pairing you've given has a "lift" to singular cohomology: $([\alpha],[\beta]) \rightarrow \langle [\alpha] \cup [\beta], [M] \rangle$. Up to a sign, homotopy equivalences of compact manifolds always preserve the fundamental class, and so this definition of the bilinear form is a homotopy invariant, up to a sign.

Comment: clean ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Nice. Thanks for answering.